# How to check string or condition javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I have a very basic question.

I have a string which comes from server

```
const data = 'BUYING';
```

I have one object with which I check the server string,

```
const status = {
   buying: 'BUYING',
   closed: 'CLOSED'
}

const isClosed =
      data === status?.buying || status?.closed
```

So this does not work when I add `|| for another key`

How do I compare the string with `||`

Thanks.

Comment: `data === status?.buying || status?.closed` is the same as `data === (status?.buying || status?.closed)` which is comparing `data` to `true` or `false`. You probably want `data === status?.buying || data === status?.closed`.

Comment: What are you even doing? Why do you want to use || for string comparison? || ist just the logical or operator, nothing more. Just do `const isClosed = data === status.closed` and you are done.

Comment: actually, data string from server it can be either closed or buying so I need to add that or condition

Comment: wdym?, if `data` is equal to `CLOSED` then it's closed, otherwisde its not.

Comment: The question is it can either be closed or buying so, wanted to check with or condition

Comment: so you want to know if it's either `CLOSED` or `BUYING`? Then why do you call the variable `isClosed` and not `isClosedOrBuying`? This is not what you wrote in your question.

Comment: You said *"it can be either be closed or buying"*. So, as mentioned in one of the previous comments `const isClosed = data === status.closed` should work?

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to check if status is closed as your variable name defines.

```
const isClosed = data === status?.closed;
```

If you need to check if status is either buying or closed then you should use:

```
const isClosed = data === status?.buying || data === status?.closed;
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try a third operator like:

`const isClosed = data === status?.buying ? true : false`